# Create a data frame from loop

Tags: r, date, loops, dataframe, subset

How do I create a data frame for wkend rather than not print it?

```
wkend<-as.Date(c("2013-01-04","2013-01-05","2013-01-06"),"%Y-%m-%d")
while(wkend < "2013-12-27") { 
   wkend <- wkend + 7
print(wkend)
 }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Since you are quite new here, you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of it. If an answer does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adjust your last day by one if you want to have a `data.frame` otherwise you will have uneven rows. But you can use `lapply` to apply the `seq.Date` function to each element in your `wkend` vector like this:

```
df <- data.frame( lapply( wkend , seq , to = as.Date( "2013-12-26" , "%Y-%m-%d" ) , by = 7 ) )
names( df ) <- c("Col1","Col2","Col3") # Call the columns whatever you want
head(df)
    Col1       Col2       Col3
1 2013-01-04 2013-01-05 2013-01-06
2 2013-01-11 2013-01-12 2013-01-13
3 2013-01-18 2013-01-19 2013-01-20
4 2013-01-25 2013-01-26 2013-01-27
5 2013-02-01 2013-02-02 2013-02-03
6 2013-02-08 2013-02-09 2013-02-10
```